# Removing a shortcut with a batch file on a windows 8.1 desktop deployed through sccm

Tags: batch-file

I have a question that has eluded me for a little while. I am deploying a script with sccm and it installs a couple of programs and is supposed to remove a shortcut from a users desktop.

The trouble I'm having is that everything deploys fine but the shortcut doesn't get removed.

When I run the batch file locally on a test computer it removed it fine.

Can someone please help me as to why it doesn't want to get removed when i deploy it through sccm?

Here is my code for the batch file:

```
   :: Installs refresh app 
\\server\program.exe" /VERYSILENT  

:: Removes shortcut
del /F /Q "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\shortcut.lnk"

:: Adds new software
xcopy "\\server\program1.exe" "%userprofile%\desktop"
```

Comment: Does the `xcopy` command line work as expected, but the `del` command line fails?

Comment: Yes, the del command doesn't work and I can't seem to figure out why. When I run it on a test machine it deletes the .lnk file but doesn't when I deploy the script. I have also tried using ℅alluserprofiles℅ directory and that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Is the script running on the server or on the client? Does the script run as a user with administrative privileges? Does the user have sufficient privileges to delete files on the Desktop?

Comment: The script is deployed to install for the system through sccm, so it automatically will take the admin privileges of the machine and execute the script.